# How do I join an online party in White Knight Chronicles?

Tags: ps3, white-knight-chronicles

I need to join a party to be able to complete some quests. I have visited another players town, but I have not been able to join any party. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have someone to group with? You're asking for the actual commands to group with someone ?

Comment: @Khez Not anyone in particular. When I find a group, how do I join it? Alternatively; How do I create a group and invite others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go into GeoNet, accessible via Save Point Logic Stone) and World Map. Sign in and accept the user agreement. Go to hometown find the Quest Officer near the entrance of town and either join someone already questing or create a quest yourself.

This is highly dependent on how many people are online I believe. Post if this doesn't work for you.

[Source](http://www.justpushstart.com/game-guides/white-knight-chronicles-geonet-tutorial/).

Comment: @MizardX this didn't work ?!

Comment: I didn't have a chance to test it until now.